# What is maven -D meaning?

Tags: maven

I saw some maven commands which have `-D` inside. For example:

```
mvn clean install -Duser=john -Dpw=122345
```

I cannot find anything about it on the internet. Can someone show me some official documentation on what it means?

Comment: this is how you pass the parameter - for official documentation please go to Maven official documentation :)

Comment: Here you can check all maven command line arguments  https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-embedder/cli.html

Answer (score 6):

Command line tools usually have a `--help` option that you can use to find this info.
Doing `mvn --help` yields this info about `-D`:

```
-D,--define <arg>                      Define a system property
```

Answer (score 4):

`-Dname=value` is declaring variable with name "name" and value "value".

This variable can be used in `pom.xml` like this `${name}`. Such expression will by replaced by "value".

**Example**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
        <artifactId>lolipop-factory</artifactId>
        <version>${name}</version>
    </dependency>
```

will in fact work as

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
        <artifactId>lolipop-factory</artifactId>
        <version>value</version>
    </dependency>
```

if you run it as `mvn -Dname=value compile`

It could be accessed from maven plugins as well.

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful. Is there any other place except for pom.xml where you could use -D parameter ? And how can you use the replaced value in the pom.xml . I know about Spring boot who uses this tecnic

Comment: @Toni26 I extended my answer a bit.